# failed to find version script file when linking a dynamic library by using bazel cluster

Tags: c++, version, cluster-computing, bazel, dynamic-library

I was building a shared/dynamic library by using `bazel`. The rules in `Build` file are like below

```
cc_library(
    name = "a",
    srcs = ["a.cc"]
)

filegroup(
    name = "vis_ld",
    srcs = ["tool/vis.ld"]
)

cc_library(
    name = "b",
    hdrs = ["b.h"],
    srcs = ["b.cc"],
    deps = [":a"],
)

cc_binary(
    name = "libgeta.so",
    deps = [":b"],
    linkshared = True,
    linkopts = [
        "-Wl,--version-script,","$(location :vis_ld)"
    ],
    data = [":vis_ld"]
)
```

The `libgeta.so` is target binary file. As we known from the rule, there exists a version script file that limits the exported symbols. Here's the wired thing, if I built `libgeta.so` locally, it works fine. When I tried to build with bazel cluster, it fails with following error.

```
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: cannot open tool/vs.ld: No such file or directory
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/ld.gold: fatal error: unable to parse version script file tool/vs.ld
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

the bazel version I was using is `0.24.1`.

It has confused me for days, please help. Thanks!

I tried to generate `vs.ld` file with Rule `genrule` at compile-time, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version script needs to go into the `deps` attribute of the `cc_binary` rather than `data`.

(Also, Bazel 0.24.1 is very old.)

Comment: how？`deps` only takes targets of `cc_library`

Comment: it also takes version scripts files